# Как изменить скорость видео с помощью ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, видео

Мне нужно с помощью ffmpeg ускорить видео, скажем, раз в двадцать пять, и я уже года два не могу добиться успехов в этом направлении.

Что я пытался:

- использовать setpts согласно документации:

  ```
  ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf setpts=PTS/25 output.mp4
  ```

  видео действительно ускоряется, однако готовый файл имеет 625 кадров в секунду и, как следствие, не воспроизводится ни одним плеером;
- урезать частоту кадров с помощью фильтра fps:

  ```
  ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf setpts=PTS/25,fps=fps=25 output.mp4
  ```

  в итоге первые 1/25 времени ролик воспроизводятся как и ожидается, а последующие 24/25 времени отображается последний кадр видео — общая длительность видео оказалась равна исходной, несмотря на изменение скорости;
- сделать финт ушами и поменять фильтры местами (надеялся ускорить 1fps видео до 25 кадров):

  ```
  ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf fps=fps=1,setpts=PTS/25 output.mp4
  ```

  в итоге получилось дёрганое непонятно что с непонятно какой частотой кадров (хотя VLC формально заявляет 25 кадров, на деле там похоже что-то переменное);
- урезать частоту кадров опцией -r:

  ```
  ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf setpts=PTS/25 -r 25 output.mp4
  ```

  как и в первом случае, частота почему-то оказалась 625 кадров в секунду и файл не воспроизводится ни одним плеером.

Так как же нормально изменить скорость видео?

Comment: Последняя команда все верно сделала. Получилось как и задумано 25 кадров. Еще я попробовал `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -lavfi "setpts=0.04*PTS" -r 30 -c:v rawvideo output-x25.mp4`, тоже работает, идея взята [отсюда](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7617)

Comment: @TotalPusher крайне странно, что у вас это работает, ведь rawvideo не поддерживается контейнером mp4 и при попытке запустить эту команду ffmpeg вообще выбивает ошибку и ничего не делает

Comment: @TotalPusher а ещё у меня последняя команда из вопроса и правда стала верно работать, тоже странно...

Answer (score 0):

Замените

```
-vf setpts=PTS/25,fps=fps=25 -r 25
```

на

```
-vf setpts=PTS*0.04,fps=fps=25  -r 25
```

Деление не работает